# how do u append lines from text file into a fixed text

Tags: bash, awk

I have a txt file query.txt with lines like:

```
where is the sports game
where is the election
where is the war
```

and I need to get a new file processed_query.txt with the following output
I gave particular details of the file where I had issues

```
Query: $line Response: User Input
```

where $line is the each line from query.txt file.

I tried using

```
while read -r line; do
    "Query: $line Response: User Input"
```

but I don't know if I don't seem to get the right output as a string.

Comment: You are missing the word `echo`.  Is that really not present?  As in `echo Query: $line...`

Comment: You're also missing `done`. As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". See also [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: From your code, you should get a _command not found_ error, since you are running the string `"Query: $line Response: User Input"` as a command. What do you want to do with the string?

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it trivially with both `awk` and `sed`. Simply append the text you want around each line (record) processed, e.g.

**Using awk**

With `awk` you can simply append strings by placing them next to each other in a `print` statement. In `awk` the entire record is represented by `$0` (the first field as `$1`, the second `$2`, and so on...). So all you need is:

```bash
awk '{print "Query: " $0 " Response: User Input"}' file > processed_query.txt
```

(where your input is in `file` and you are simply redirecting the output to your `processed_query.txt` file)

Remove the `> processed_query.txt` to see the output printed to your terminal.

**Using sed**

With `sed` the basic substitute method (e.g. `sed 's/find/replace/'`) will do. You match the entire line with the simple REGEX `^.*$` and use `&` to reinsert the matched expression, e.g.

```bash
sed 's/^.*$/Query: & Response: User Input/' file > processed_query.txt
```

(**note:** you can also use numbered backreferences in `sed` to accomplish the same reinsertion -- it's just a few more characters of typing in this case. If your curious, the substitute expression becomes `'s/\(^.*$\)/Query: \1 Response: User Input/'` using Basic Regular Expressions. With Extended Regular Expressions you can avoid escaping the parenthesis)

**Example Use/Output**

In both cases, the text written to your new file will be:

```
$ sed 's/^.*$/Query: & Response: User Input/' file
Query: where is the sports game Response: User Input
Query: where is the election Response: User Input
Query: where is the war Response: User Input
```

For large data sets, `awk` or `sed` will always be much faster than looping in a shell script. For a few thousand lines of input, it doesn't really make any difference.

Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by *[@Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts)*, you are probably missing an `echo` statement.

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "Query: $line Response: User Input" >> "$output_file"
done < "$input_file"
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/MenacingAgonizingBrains#main.sh)***